# How to add Date validation in regexp of Spark-Sql

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("select case when length(regexp_replace(date,'[^0-9]', ''))==8 then regexp_replace(date,'[^0-9]', '') else regexp_replace(date,'[^0-9]','') end as date from input").show(false)
```

In the above I need to add the requirements such as,

1.the output should be validated with the format '`yyyymmdd`' using unix_timestamp.

2. if it is not valid then should transform the extracted digits string by moving the first four (4) characters to the end of the extracted digits string (`MMDDYYYY to YYYYMMDD`) and then should be validated with the '`yyyymmdd`' format, if this condition is satisfied then print that date.

I'm not sure how to include the Unix timestamp in my query.

Sample input and output 1:

```
input: 2021dgsth02hdg02
output: 20210202
```

Sample input and output 2:

```
input: 0101def20dr21 (note: MMDDYYYY TO YYYYMMDD)
output: 20210101
```

Using unix_timestamp in place of to_date

```
spark.sql("select (case when length(regexp_replace(date,'[^0-9]', ''))==8 then CASE WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(date,'[a-zA-Z]+',''),'yyyyMMdd') ,'yyyyMMdd') IS NULL THEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(date,'[a-zA-Z]+',''),'MMddyyyy') ,'MMddyyyy') ELSE from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace(date,'[a-zA-Z]+',''),'yyyyMMdd') ,'yyyyMMdd') END else regexp_replace(date,'[^0-9]','') end ) AS dt from input").show(false)
```

Comment: can you share same input & output ?

Comment: I've added the sample input and outputs now. please check @Srinivas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below code.

```
scala> val df = Seq("2021dgsth02hdg02","0101def20dr21").toDF("dt")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [dt: string]
```

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----------------+
|dt              |
+----------------+
|2021dgsth02hdg02|
|0101def20dr21   |
+----------------+
```

```
scala> df
.withColumn("dt",regexp_replace($"dt","[a-zA-Z]+",""))
.withColumn("dt",
    when(
        to_date($"dt","yyyyMMdd").isNull,
        to_date($"dt","MMddyyyy")
    )
    .otherwise(to_date($"dt","yyyyMMdd"))
).show(false)
```

```
+----------+
|dt        |
+----------+
|2021-02-02|
|2021-01-01|
+----------+
```

---

```
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

spark.sql("""
    select (
        CASE WHEN to_date(regexp_replace(date,'[a-zA-Z]+',''),'yyyyMMdd') IS NULL
             THEN to_date(regexp_replace(date,'[a-zA-Z]+',''),'MMddyyyy')
             ELSE to_date(regexp_replace(date,'[a-zA-Z]+',''),'yyyyMMdd')
        END
    ) AS dt from input
""")
.show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```

```
+----------+
|dt        |
+----------+
|2021-02-02|
|2021-01-01|
+----------+
```

Comment: I think this works, but can you please show it with my code, because the statement should not involve withcolumn . The format is CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END .@Srinivas

Comment: check now i have updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I have two more questions! Why can't we use unix_timestamp as I've cused in my query? could you please alter your answer to that and if the input is given as 2201edfgr2021 the output should be 22012021 the numeric characters alone but it is returning null. could you please alter this ?@Srinivas

Comment: Why because according to your code, it is return the date format as 2021-01-01, but the expected result is 20210101..@Srinivas

Comment: Sure, can you please tell me your excepted output column data type ?

Comment: It should be a string with YYYYMMDD format, i think I'm able to achieve this format by using the query with unix_timestamp which i've mentioned in latest edit. But as I asked before if the input is 2201edfgr2021 the output should be 22012021 the numeric characters but the query is giving NULL. could you please alter that alone.@Srinivas

Comment: you can use `unix_timestamp` if you want to capture complete timestamp.. if you want to only date you can use `to_date` function. by looking at your question your requirement is only to capture date not timestamp.